Pandas Add Index to MultiIndex
I am creating a MultiIndex using the following code:
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df['Day'].tolist(), ['A','B','C']], 
    names=['Day', 'Status'])

Which creates:
MultiIndex([('01-Jun', 'A'),
            ('01-Jun', 'B'),
            ('01-Jun', 'C'),
            ('02-Jun', 'A'),
            ('02-Jun', 'B'),
            ('02-Jun', 'C')],
            ...
       names=['Day', 'Status'])

How would I insert a static index at the beginning so the output would look like:
MultiIndex([('VALUE1', 'VALUE2'),
            ('01-Jun', 'A'),
            ('01-Jun', 'B'),
            ('01-Jun', 'C'),
            ('02-Jun', 'A'),
            ('02-Jun', 'B'),
            ('02-Jun', 'C')],
            ...
       names=['Day', 'Status'])


What's the end goal? It seems strange to insert a non-day into the "day" level. Beware the XY problem; give the context.

Indexes have an .insert() method.
idx.insert(0, ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2'))

MultiIndex([('VALUE1', 'VALUE2'),
            ('01-Jun',      'A'),
            ('01-Jun',      'B'),
            ('01-Jun',      'C'),
            ('02-Jun',      'A'),
            ('02-Jun',      'B'),
            ('02-Jun',      'C')],
           names=['Day', 'Status'])

Setup for reference
days = ['01-Jun', '02-Jun']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [days, ['A','B','C']],
    names=['Day', 'Status'])


I have union in mind, but for a single value insert is nicer ;)

@mozway That was what I thought of first myself, then I realized OP said "insert" and I thought "lists have an insert method; do indexes?" :)

You can create a new MultiIndex with the static index inserted using from_tuples method:
tuples = [('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')] + list(idx)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Day', 'Status'])


first convert you static input to multi-index and then simply append, as shown below,
import pandas as pd 
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['sun', 'mon', 'tue'], ['A','B','C']], 
                           names=['Day', 'Status'])

###your input
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('val1', 'val2')], names=['Day', 'Status'])
idx2.append(idx1)

MultiIndex([('val1', 'val2'),
            ( 'sun',    'A'),
            ( 'sun',    'B'),
            ( 'sun',    'C'),
            ( 'mon',    'A'),
            ( 'mon',    'B'),
            ( 'mon',    'C'),
            ( 'tue',    'A'),
            ( 'tue',    'B'),
            ( 'tue',    'C')],
           names=['Day', 'Status'])


You can use a union:
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['01-Jun', '02-Jun'], ['A','B','C']], 
    names=['Day', 'Status'])

idx = (pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')], names=idx.names)
         .union(idx, sort=False)
      )

Output:
MultiIndex([('VALUE1', 'VALUE2'),
            ('01-Jun',      'A'),
            ('01-Jun',      'B'),
            ('01-Jun',      'C'),
            ('02-Jun',      'A'),
            ('02-Jun',      'B'),
            ('02-Jun',      'C')],
           names=['Day', 'Status'])

